# Delete ARO nodes progmatically in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I've got a simple ARO/ACO set up with simply all my users as AROs and all my Modules as ACOs and the ARO_ACOs table holds the permission rights.

This works great, except when I delete a User, I'd like to be able to clean up the ARO_ACOs and ARO tables by removing any entries associated with the ARO related to the user.

How do I go about this? The documentation is not helpful at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using the ACL behavior? No action required

Assuming [the acl behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/acl.html) is in use, there's no need to do anything as it [automatically deletes acl records for aros/acos](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Model/Behavior/AclBehavior.php#L125-L142), which will also delete the permission records at the same time.

Comment: Ahh Thank you AD7six, I haven't been using the ACL behavior in its correct form. I'll implement this later today and get back to you.